# How do I get my multi-tenant Azure Function to access resources in another tenant?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-identity

I'm fairly confident I set everything up right for a multi-tenant app.

In Tenant A:
I created an Azure function and enabled a system managed identity. I granted the Managed Identity permissions to the Graph API. I confirmed my API can obtain an access token for the Managed Identity and access the Graph API with it. I added Azure AD authentication to the app and created an App Registration for the app. I configured the necessary Graph API permissions in the API Permissions settings of the app registration. I also enabled the various options to enable multi-tenant access.

In Tenant B:
I accessed the special URL to start the admin consent process for the app in Tenant A. I confirmed that I was prompted to consent to the permissions that I specified in the app registration in Tenant A. I can see that a couple new enterprise application entries were created in Tenant B for the app in Tenant A.

So far so good. However, no matter what I do, I cannot obtain a token to access the graph API in the context of Tenant B. It ALWAYS gives me a token for the managed identity in Tenant A, and accesses the info in Tenant A.

The code the retrieves an access token using the managed identity is here:

```
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { AdditionallyAllowedTenants = { "*" }, TenantId = "<Tenant B ID>" });
        var token = credential.GetToken(
            new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
                new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }, null, null, "<Tenant B ID"));
        var accessToken = token.Token;
```

Now, I have tried all sorts of different combinations here. But, from everything I read, I am supposed to be able to specify the Tenant ID of another tenant in these methods and obtain an access token for that specific tenant. However, even when I specify Tenant B's ID, I always get a token back for the managed identity in Tenant A. If I use the token, of course, I end up accessing all of Tenant A's information.

Ironically, if I remove the `DefaultAzureCredentialOptions` and include the tenantID in the `GetToken` request I get an error telling me that I'm trying to obtain a token for a different tenant (than my own) and that I need to add the `AdditionallyAllowedTenants` option. It clears the error up when I add that, but then it doesn't obtain a token for the other tenant.

Perhaps I am still approaching this wrong. I want to host a multi-tenant Azure Function that runs in the context of the Tenant where the request originated from to access information within that tenant using a managed identity that exists within that tenant. I can obtain the Tenant ID context from the claims sent to the Azure function during authentication, but no matter how I try to specify that Tenant ID in my code, it will not get a token for that Tenant.

**UPDATE and SOLUTION:**
Thanks to Philippe's great write up, I did finally get this. I had some confusion around the mechanisms at play here and want to add this note for clarity on how I solved it.

If you've followed most of the documents you have an Azure Function app in your "host" tenant A, with an associated app registration in tenant A. The app registration has certain API permissions configured, and you have consented to this app and permissions in Tenant B.

To access the resources in Tenant B, you need to create a secret key or certificate on the app registration in Tenant A. You then need to authenticate using the Client ID, and secret key/certificate of the app registration in Tenant A, but you will request a token for Tenant B. Here it is in code using a certificate for authentication:

```html
var appToken = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantID, appID, appCert, new ClientCertificateCredentialOptions { AdditionallyAllowedTenants = { "*" } });
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(appToken);
```

Here, we assign the following to the variables:

- tenantID = Tenant B's ID
- appID = Tenant A's App registration client ID
- appCert = Tenant A's App registration cert

We have to include the AdditionallyAllowedTenants config parameter, and the `*` authorizes a token from any tenant. We then take that credential and use it to build a new `GraphServiceClient` that is connected to Tenant B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created two separate and independent identities for your service:

1. The managed identity: You don't need to deal with credentials, but this identity can only be used within the same tenant. You can't use your managed identity to directly access another tenant, and you can't (currently) use your managed identity to authenticate as your app registration.
2. The app registration: This identity *can* be used to access data in another tenant, but (currently) you *do* need to deal with credentials.

The [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) will attempt different ways of authenticating until it finds one that works:

- First, it first tries to authenticate using an [EnvironmentCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet). This will look for certain environment variables needed to authenticate. Depending on the variables it finds, it will end up creating a [ClientSecretCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-dotnet) (to authenticate using the app's client secret) or [ClientCertificateCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientcertificatecredential?view=azure-dotnet) (using an app's client certificate).
- Next, if no suitable environment variables were found, it tries to authenticate using [ManagedIdentityCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-dotnet), which (as the name suggests) will attempt to use a managed identity. For you, this will always succeed (because there *is* a managed identity available to be used).
- Next, if no managed identity was available, it will continue trying with various other options. This is all described in detail [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#key-concepts).

For your scenario, you basically have two options today.

### Option 1, using DefaultAzureCredential and environment variables

Place the credentials for your multi-tenant app registration in environment variables and your existing code will "just work".

For example:

- `AZURE_TENANT_ID` - the target tenant where you want to obtain the token
- `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` - your multi-tenant app registration's app ID
- `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` - a client secret for your multi-tenant app registration

> Note: In general, it is better to use a certificate than a secret.

### Option 2, using ClientSecretCredential or ClientCertificateCredential

Instead of using [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet), you can directly create a [ClientSecretCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-dotnet) or a [ClientCertificateCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientcertificatecredential?view=azure-dotnet). You'll need to store the credential somewhere safe.

For example, on approach you could follow which would avoid any credentials in environment variable or in code:

1. Store credentials for your multi-tenant app in a key vault.
2. Allow your function's managed identity to access the credential in the key vault.
3. In your function, use your managed identity to retrieve the credential from Key Vault (e.g. using ManagedIdentityCredential), in your tenant.
4. Use that credential to authenticate as your multi-tenant app registration, in the target tenant (i.e. ClientSecretCredential or ClientCertificateCredential)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme

Comment: You were spot on. Your write up led me astray and I started trying to create an app registration with certificate credential in every child tenant and store that in a key vault. I then was trying to use the app's managed identity to retrieve and use the credential for the child tenant. I overlooked the concept that I am supposed to be using the app registration and credential in the host tenant and requesting the token for the child tenant ID. Worked like a charm. Wow, so much more straightforward. I may come in here and make a few edits to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Managed Identities can only get tokens within the tenant that they exist in.
You'd need a "traditional" multi-tenant app registration + client certificate/secret for this case.