# How to connect an Azure Function in tenant1 with an Azure SQL database in tenant2?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

In `tenant1` Azure Function, there is a Python function to connect to an Azure SQL database:

```
import aioodbc
import logging


async def create_db_connection(SERVER_NAME: str, DATABASE_NAME: str, USERNAME: str, PASSWORD: str) -> aioodbc.Connection: 
    CONNECTION_STRING = (
        'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
        f'Server=tcp:{SERVER_NAME}.database.windows.net,1433;'
        f'Database={DATABASE_NAME};Uid={USERNAME};Pwd={PASSWORD};'
        'Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'
    )
    conn = await retry(aioodbc.connect, dsn=CONNECTION_STRING, autocommit=True)
    logging.info(f'##### Azure SQL Server connection successfully created')
    return conn
```

Is it possible to use `tenant2`'s `SERVER_NAME`, `DATABASE_NAME`, `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` to connect to the database?

Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: What do you mean by tenant ? do you mean different Subscriptions ?

Comment: Completely separate companies with different Azure AD tenants, definitely different Subscriptions.

Comment: Well then make sure to use connection string provided in the portal  it should work . but I think the issue would be with firewall make sure to either whitelist the Ip addresses of function app listed in the networking tab or open up the sql server to all the trafic

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the applications like SQL Database from the different Azure Tenant, then your application should have access level to be multi-tenant configured.

- Register the SQL database server in an App Registration.
- Provide/Grant the Application Permissions such as `Directory.ReadAll` and Delegated Permissions.
- User should be authenticated with that Application with the right permissions for accessing.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/azure-ad-authentication-sql-server-setup-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver16#create-and-register-an-azure-ad-application) and [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73944916) for more information on accessing the multi-tenant configured applications.